# AngularJS, How to install ngMaterial with bower?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have difficulties to install ngMaterial. I'm using Ruby on Rails with the bower gem. Here is what I have:

Bowerfile:

```
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
asset 'angular-animate', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-ui'
asset 'angular-sanitize'
asset 'angular-mocks', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-route', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-resource', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-messages', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-material'
asset 'angular', '~> 1.6'
```

myapp_app.js

```
var app = angular.module(
    'argumentation',[
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'templates',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial'
]);
```

After doing `rake bower:install`, when I open my page, this error occurs:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module argumentation due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ngMaterial
```

I tried to find the spelling error, but I found none (can someone see a spelling error?).

I noticed this: `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ngMaterial`
The newest version of angular-material is `1.1.1` and in the link there is `1.6.1.` This may be the problem, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

The error report also mentions, that I should add dependencies: `If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument` .But I don't know, which dependencies I have to add and how.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

I added the version to ngMaterial, but the same error remains:

```
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
asset 'angular-animate', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-ui'
asset 'angular-sanitize'
asset 'angular-mocks', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-route', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-resource', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-messages', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-material', '~> 1.1.1'
asset 'angular', '~> 1.6
```

'EDIT 2:

As atulquest93 commented, I forgot to add angular-material to the js file. Now, another error occured, namely, that ngAria is not found. I added ngAria and now, it seems to work, but for some reason, the background color changed to white.

Thanks to atulquest93

bowerfile:

```
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
asset 'angular-animate', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-ui'
asset 'angular-sanitize'
asset 'angular-mocks', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-route', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-resource', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-messages', '~> 1.6'
asset 'angular-material', '~> 1.1.1'
asset 'angular', '~> 1.6'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-material
//= require angular-aria
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Just double checking: did you include the ngMaterial `.js` file via `<script src="..."></script>` in your HTML?

Comment: No, but I don't have to do this with all the other assets. Is this an exception for ngMaterial?

Comment: Nope! Btw `1.1.1` IS definitely the latest version of angular-material, but `1.6.1` refers to the latest version of Angular that you're using..  so maybe you wanna try specifying `1.1.1` for angular-material in your Bowerfile? (I'm not familiar w/ using Bower w/ Ruby, so this is merely just a suggestion.)

Comment: You need to include `material.js` file yourself to the code.